# How can I speed up typing in protractor or set a longer timeout time

Tags: selenium, testing, protractor, protractor-net

How can I speed up typing in protractor?

I get a runtime error if my textbox words are long

```
    var addText = element.all(by.css('.control-18u')).get(3);
    expect(addText).toBeDefined();
    addText.clear();
    addText.sendKeys('OK').then(function () {
    console.log("Added Text");
    })
```

When I run the following with `addText.sendKeys('OK')` it takes a while but passes,When I use something like `addText.sendKeys('Tester 1 All good')`

My Question is how can I add more text without it timing out **OR** how can I set a longer timeout session

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation about timeouts?

http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

Answer (score 0):

```
addText.sendKeys('OK this could take a second or two').then(function() {
  console.log("Added Text");
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing does take long. This is a common issue with IE 64-bit driver. Install the 32-bit driver and it works perfectly.